# Net force and direction of motion are opposite. What's the problem here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

In the figure shown above, there's a block, lying on a smooth plank, with uniform distribution of mass and weighs 3 kg and is of length 30 cm. Pulleys and strings are ideal. The question asks for the force that the "10 cm part" of the block exerts on the "20 cm part". The question seems easy enough and we can find out the acceleration of the whole system as 4m/s^2 towards the right, treating the two parts as a single body.

Now first please tell me if I have defined normal contact force properly: It's basically a electromagnetic force(by nature) which is exerted by one body on another body which is in contact with it, in the direction perpendicular to the contact of surface and away from the exerting body.

If my understanding of normal force is correct, (which I don't think is), then when we make the free body diagram for the "10 cm part", we see that two forces i.e. the tension (20N) and the normal contact force exerted by the "20 cm part", are in the same direction (leftwards).

Now, the "10 cm part" has net forces acting only leftwards and it's moving rightwards, which actually defies Newton's laws and so is incorrect.

Where's the flaw in my whole thinking process?

Thanks in advance and please forgive me for silly mistakes(if any!)

Comment: Actually, the problem with my method clicked me. If I treat two bodies as different, then there won't be any normal force acting because the two bodies won't stay in contact any more. But then how to find the force acting between the two parts of the blocks??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal force where two inert surfaces make contact is generally a compression force.

But if you were to saw your single block into two pieces, the external forces wouldn't compress them together: the rope on the left would pull the smaller piece to the left, and the rope on the right would pull the larger piece to the right.  In order to restore the move-together behavior, you'd have to fill the gap with a little rope that would be under some tension, or with glue whose long sticky molecules act like lots and lots of little ropes under tension.  Or you could reconnect the two pieces with a clamp, which would exert a compression force from the other side.

Comment: Thank you sir. That really gave some "high frequency light" on my knowledge!! :-D